# Updating fixtures?

Tags: ember.js

I'm following the official [Ember guide](http://emberjs.com/guides) to do a Todo app.

Is it possible to do a persistent change to the fixtures? If so, how? Because with the code I have, clicking the check box doesn't save the value persistently to the fixtures.

index.html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos">
  <ul id="todo-list">
    {{#each itemController="todo"}}
      <li {{bind-attr class="isCompleted:completed"}}>
        {{input type="checkbox" checked=isCompleted class="toggle"}}
        <label>{{title}}</label><button class="destroy"></button>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

application.js:

```
window.Todos = Ember.Application.create();
Todos.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();
```

models/todo.js:

```
Todos.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean')
});

Todos.Todo.FIXTURES = [
 {
   id: 1,
   title: 'Learn Ember.js',
   isCompleted: true
 }
];
```

controllers/todo_controller.js:

```
Todos.TodoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isCompleted: function(key, value){
    var model = this.get('model');

    if (value === undefined) {
      // property being used as a getter
      return model.get('isCompleted');
    } else {
      // property being used as a setter

      model.set('isCompleted', value);
      model.save();
      return value;
    }
  }.property('model.isCompleted')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so. At the end of that tutorial, there's a section for replacing the fixture adapter with local storage so that you get real persistence. http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/using-other-adapters/

*js/application.js*

```
window.Todos = Ember.Application.create();

Todos.ApplicationAdapter = DS.LSAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'todos-emberjs'
});
```

*index.html*

```
<!--- ... additional lines truncated for brevity ... -->
<script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/localstorage_adapter.js"></script>
<script src="js/application.js"></script>
 <!--- ... additional lines truncated for brevity ... -->
```